# How do you disable the internet for one user in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking

Like ***really*** disable it, as if the computer had it's networkcard removed and that any attempt at trying to access the networkcard should be as if it didn't exist.

To clarify:
All the user accounts are on the same computer.

Comment: If you have a linux based firewall/router you could use iptables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [netcut](http://www.arcai.com/) software. It's free  to download and can disconnect the internet of other user sharing same internet.

Answer (score 0):

If you use LAN Connection, you could try this

- Create a new user group
- Add a standard user to this group
- Set up a LAN connection using Network and Sharing Center
- Now change parameters ( such as IP, domain, DNS) in LAN Connection properties to a value which doesn't work.
- Go to Group Policy Editor -> <Group_Name> -> Administrative Templates -> Network -> Network Connections -> Prohibit access to properties of LAN connection.

Comment: can you clarify on this part? ` *Set up a LAN connection with non-existent values` I've never done this before, all I managed to do was find where gpedit program was on the harddisc and saw the overwhelming amount of options =